# What would be the advantage(s) of using try-catch instead of return in a recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I once saw a recursive function that went like this:

```
function findNode(tree) {
  var NODE = {};
  function traverse(node) {
    for (var child in node.children) {
      if (testNode(child)) {
        NODE.value = child;
        throw NODE;
      }
      traverse(child);
    }
  }

  try {
    traverse(tree);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e === NODE)
      return NODE.value;
  }
}
```

Is this a good usage of try-catch? How does this compare to, for example, returning and checking the value of a traverse() call?

Comment: It could be slightly faster in some cases. I did something similar as a microoptimization in a transpiler that compiled some toy language to Javascript, but that was to break out of a 1000-call-deep call stack, and the Javascript wasn't intended to be read by humans.

Comment: For ordinary code, I wouldn't do anything like that.

Comment: For the achievement of algorithm, using try-catch probably doesn't workout in case of searching for multiple nodes that satisfy `testNode`.

Comment: The equivalent "return: version is considerably shorter, perhaps more readable ...`return testNode(child)? child : traverse(child);` there doesn't seem to be much point to using try .. catch here.